# Cannot read property "replace" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]`enter code here`[image]
I'm creating an online catalog and every time I click on the "more info" button, I get a cannot read property `replace` of `undefined`

I tried to rename the `property` but it still isn't working

```
let removeCom = this.props.itemInfo.description.replace("?", "").replace('<td width="110" height="">', "").replace("http://extranet.acetools.com/Catalog/","assets/img/items/").replace((/<INPUT[^>]*>/gmi), "").split('<CENTER><FONT COLOR="RED">', 1);
console.log(removeCom);
```

Comment: Such an error occurs when trying to use the function on an undefined value, `this.props.itemInfo.description` is undefined , and we will need more then just two lines to help you :)

Comment: this really isn't enough info to help you. If `this.props.itemInfo.description` is undefined, then that's something you need to work out.

Comment: You should post more code, we need to see how is `this.props` defined

Comment: give me a minute this is my first time using this site.. still trying to figure it out . thank you in advance

Comment: It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code. Then you can also inspect all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this means two things

Either itemInfo doesnt have a description or you have spelling mistake because when the javascript doesn't find the object it returns **undefined** so you are trying to access method of replace on undefined e.g undefined.replace()

hence your code becomes like this

```
let removeCom = this.props.itemInfo.undefined.replace("?", "").replace('<td width="110" height="">', "").replace("http://extranet.acetools.com/Catalog/","assets/img/items/").replace((/<INPUT[^>]*>/gmi), "").split('<CENTER><FONT COLOR="RED">', 1)
console.log(removeCom);
```

other for safer approach you can do this

```
let { itemInfo } = this.props;
let removeCom;
if(itemInfo.description){
   removeCom  = itemInfo.description.replace("?", "").replace('<td width="110" height="">', "").replace("http://extranet.acetools.com/Catalog/","assets/img/items/").replace((/<INPUT[^>]*>/gmi), "").split('<CENTER><FONT COLOR="RED">', 1)
   console.log(removeCom);

}
```

Comment: if i do that i get another error saying "removeCom"  no-undef

Comment: i have updated the bottom last code, so u wont be getting any errors about removeCom

Comment: wow that worked! can you explain what i did wrong and what you did right? im new to stackoverflow and new to coding

Comment: in your code sometimes, iteminfo would recieve description property and sometime it wasn't recieving description property so i added an if condition so that if it has a description property then it will execute the code otherwise it will not,

kindly mark the answer as correct and dont forget to upvote the answer, thanks

Comment: how do i mark the answer as correct and upvote . im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Hey Danial Shabbir is there any way i can get in contact with you i have a couple of questions with the current project that you just helped me on

Comment: after that i got (above picture) as a result but for some reason it isnt grabbing "item image"

Comment: yes ofcourse franky viray, here is my email danialmaluk7@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `description` is undefined. You might want to check to make sure that prop is being passed to the component properly.

You can also try setting the description to a default value, so you don't get the "cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error.

```
const { itemInfo: { description = '' } = this.props;
let removeCom = description.replace("?", "").replace('<td width="110" height="">', "").replace("http://extranet.acetools.com/Catalog/","assets/img/items/").replace((/<INPUT[^>]*>/gmi), "").split('<CENTER><FONT COLOR="RED">', 1);
```